# Random Connection aborted TimeoutError 10060 in python API

Tags: python, networking, soap

I'm using python socket to connect to a server but *sometimes* I get the following exceptions one after the other:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

---

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))
```

---

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))
```

I am attempting to connect to a server with SOAP. It works fine 99% the time but I receive the above error every now and then. I have spoken to the server engineers and can confirm that the server did receive my request and sent back a response (usually within 0.1s). The problem only started about 2 weeks ago and I have attempted to run the code from various VPS as well to the same result.

My timeout is 20s, so I don't think its that.

My code is fairly simple:

```
def fire_request(session, headers, payload):
    res = session.request("POST", "https://url/SOAP.aspx", data=payload.strip(), headers=headers)
    return res.content
```

Why am I seeing this error? And how do I solve the problem?

Comment: Where are you connecting to? What address/port?

Comment: I am connecting to https://webservices.iress.com.au/ port 443